# copy command blocks other sessions in postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm importing data from CSV file into Postgres table using `copy from` command like this

`copy tbl_name(col1, col2, col3) from '/sample.csv' delimiter ',';`

the command is executed in a transaction(read-write).
while this command is executing, I'm opening a new SQL session in the new terminal, but in this new session, I'm not able to perform `select` command. It will be stuck until the transaction is committed in the first session. 
The same issue is happening when in python program I'm copying a file using `copy_expert` command of `Psycopg2`, even tho I have created connection_engine with pooling.
Is it possible to prevent Postgres from blocking the er sessions while copy-ing data into the table?

Comment: it blocks for some reason - to create correct data in database. If it will not block and you start changing data in database then you can create mess in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a general phenomenon.  There is more going on here than you are telling us.

Maybe the COPY is happening inside the same transaction as something else which acquires a strong lock (like TRUNCATE) on the same table that is being SELECTed from.  Or maybe your SELECT is invoking some user-defined-function (perhaps directly, perhaps through a trigger or something) which is acquiring a stronger lock than SELECT usually requires.

In the absence of special conditions such as those, I have no problem running COPY and SELECT at the same time.

Comment: actually I was truncating the table in the same transaction, before importing data. so I guess I need to find a different solution

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible, unless you use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, which tries to put a row lock on rows that are already locked by the `COPY`.

It is a principle in PostgreSQL that readers don't block writers and vice versa.